# Refactored method not accepting attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring

A before_action used to work but was repeated in several controllers. For example, in my articles controller I had:

```
before_action :find_author

# Show, edit, etc. methods

def find_author
  @author = Author.find(params[:article][:author_id]) unless (params[:article] == nil || params[:article][:author_id] == nil)
  if @author == nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Because multiple controllers used this before_action I placed it in the application controller and refactored to:

```
def find_author(attribute)
  controller = send(":#{attribute}")
  @author = Author.find(params[controller][:author_id]) unless (params[controller] == nil || params[controller][:author_id] == nil)
  if @author == nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

In my articles controller I added the before_action with a parameter:

```
before_action do
  find_author(article)
end
```

After refactoring tests fail with the error below (referring to the line in the articles controller). What am I doing wrong?

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `article' for

Update: I replaced `find_author(article)` with `find_author("article")`. Now I get a new error message referring to the @author line in the application controller:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `:article'

Comment: Can you post the complete articles part that you refactored ?

Comment: No, because I don't know where does "article" come from and it is actually the same thing you application asks in the error message. In the first block, it seems you don't need to call it like `find_author(attribute)` but as `find_author`. Then in the second one there's something different.

Comment: Also I am not sure you can call a parameter like `params[controller]` and not `params['controller']` or `params[:controller]`.

Comment: So in `find_author(article)` the `article` is not a variable. it's just the word "article" so that in the before_action it would replace `[controller]` with the literal letters `[:article]`. So, I'm not calling `params[controller]` as "controller" is replaced with ":article". Replacing `find_author(article)` with `find_author("article")` made no difference.

Comment: first of all I believe you should replace "controller" as it might be a reserved word. Do something like `ctrl = params["#{attribute}"]` and use it like `@author = Author.find(ctrl[:author_id]) unless (ctrl == nil || ctrl[:author_id] == nil)`. Just an idea you might try and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks I finally got it to work using in the articles controller: `find_author(params[:article])`. In the before_action: `@author = Author.find(attribute[:author_id]) unless (attribute == nil || attribute[:author_id] == nil)`.

Comment: You can DRY your code more, I don't believe send() is necessary here and you can strip your params calls like my example above.

Comment: Thanks, correct, so in the solution I'm just passing the params directly to the before method, so I'm not using the `send` method anymore (you're right that the improper use by myself of the send method was indeed the cause of the problem).

Comment: No problem, I posted a reply - Acceptance is appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove send() and try to DRY your code. One possible solution could be :

```
@author = Author.find(ctrl[:author_id]) unless 
    (ctrl == nil || ctrl[:author_id] == nil)
```

if you get rid of `send()` and use something like

```
ctrl = params["#{attribute}"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :find_author, only: Proc.new {|c| %i(article posts).include? c.controller_name }

   protected

   def find_author
       author  = params[controller_name][:author_id]
       @author = Author.find author if author
       redirect_to root_url if @author.nil?
   end
end
```

The only issue I can see here is the calling of `controller_name` will *probably* only load `application`. If it doesn't work, we can see about refactoring.